# How do I compare two different API requests to get and display duplicate values in Reactjs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have this situation:

I am receiving two different requests from API using axios. What I need to do is compare both to show if this value is duplicate.
1. one of these requests contain a nested array with a author id and the another one contains the same id. If the id are equals I will need to show the author name, that is inside *authors*.

```
render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const { authors } = this.state;

    // mapeia ids dos autores dentro de Posts
    const authorIdPost = posts.map((post) => (
      post.metadata.authorId
    ));
      console.log(authorIdPost);

      //mapeia ids de autores dentro de Autores 
    const authorId = authors.map((author) => (
      author.id
    ))  
      console.log(authorId);
```

How I can get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, are you trying to get the value in author if the values of posts and authors are the same id?

```js
const authors = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "apple"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "banana"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "orange"
  }
];
const posts = [
  {
    metadata: {
      authorId: 2
    }
  },
  {
    metadata: {
      authorId: 3
    }
  },
  {
    metadata: {
      authorId: 4
    }
  }
];

const mapItem = [];
authors.forEach(author => {
  posts.forEach(post => {
    if (author.id === post.metadata.authorId) {
      mapItem.push(author);
    }
  });
});
console.log(mapItem);
// [ { id: 2, name: 'banana' }, { id: 3, name: 'orange' } ]
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot, was really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure.~ :D

Answer (score 2):

You can store the author IDs in a set and filter the `authors` by checking if the ID is in the set to achieve linear time complexity:

```
const authorIDs = new Set(posts.map(post => post.metadata.authorId));
const duplicateAuthors = authors.filter(author => authorIDs.has(author.id));
```